# Track conversions of HubSpot Landing page while using 3rd party Form

Tags: javascript, php, hubspot

My company has been using HubSpot for leads and registrations. We recently integrated HubSpot with Salesforce and the integration has caused issues due to HubSpot deduping. Many of our customers are employees of hotels who move around to different hotels or work for multiple hotels at the same time, so we have a lot of duplicate contacts spread through multiple Accounts. When a current customer submits a form which is designed to capture new Leads, HubSpot tries to dedupe the new submission and the submission ends going on to an existing Contact. This is confusing for our Sales team and is causing more work to decipher the form submission.

HubSpot won't let us create a type of Form which will always create a new Lead regardless of a Contact existing or not.

A possible solution is to replace the HubSpot form with an embedded a 3rd party form into our HubSpot landing page which will always create a Lead on submission. This part was easy except with the 3rd party form we lose the conversion data we would've had w/ a HubSpot Form.

I contacted HubSpot Support to get advice on how to have the 3rd party form (Formstack for Salesforce) send a call out to HubSpot API that a conversion occurred. All they did was send me a link to their [Form API documentation](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form) and told me I'd have to create a backend server to make it work.

I'm familiar with coding, but I'm no web developer so I'm unsure exactly where to start. Can this be done with some php on the HS landing page? Can I utilize [this API](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/hubspot-php) that was created by someone on GitHub?

Hoping someone can just get me going in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is the other way around. I would create a workflow connected to a webhook in Hubspot that is triggered on any form submission, and then have the webhook point to a PHP (or any language) script that will analyze the submission and will create a new lead in a different system regardless.